# Calling Office Communicator via Silverlight Out of Browser

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, office-communicator

I need to invoke office communicator to create a chat window and phone call directly from Silverlight when running out of browser.  When running in browser I do this and it works pretty well:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval(String.Format("window.open(\"sip:{0}\", target=\"_self\");", sip));
```

When running out of browser as far as I have gotten is to invoke the Communicator.UIAutomation via a dynamic but honestly I don't know what to do next.

```
dynamic communicator = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Communicator.UIAutomation");
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work?  Searching has yeilded zero results.

Answer (score 0):

A couple thoughts:

Have you tried making the automated Communicator object a var, then setting a breakpoint and digging into the resulting hydrated object?  You might find some methods or properties on the object you can use to make things happen.

There's a blog [here](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blogs/george_durzi/archive/2008/03/22/automating-office-communicator-2007-using-the-microsoft-office-communicator-2007-sdk.aspx) that describes the Office Communicator SDK and has some sample projects.  I *think* you might be able to include the SDK assemblies in your OOB app and automate Communicator using Microsoft's provided SDK.

Comment: I tried the "var" trick but it sets it as an automation which is basically back to being a dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has to be preinstalled in the user machines. There's no easy way to deploy it along your Silvelright OOB application.

You will need the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=ED1CCE45-CC22-46E1-BD50-660FE6D2C98C&displaylang=en#RelatedDownloads).

You can check the documentation for more details here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office Communicator\SDK\OCSDK.chm
It mainly refers to C#, but most of it could easily be ported to Com Automation. As an example look at the following code to start a conversation

```
dynamic comm = new ActiveXObject("Communicator.UIAutomation");
dynamic msgrAdv = comm.IMessengerAdvanced;
if(msgrAdv!=null)
{
    try
    {
        object obj = msgrAdv.StartConversation(
                   1, //CONVERSATION_TYPE.CONVERSATION_TYPE_IM,
                   sipUris, // object array of signin names
                   null,
                   "Testing",
                   "1",
                   null);
        windowHandle = long.Parse(obj.ToString());
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        this.writeToTextBox(
                formReturnErrors.returnComError(ex.ErrorCode)
    );

}
```

I hope this help. Noticed that from the example in the help file I changed some of the members that are defined in the .NET Assembly (which can't be referenced from your C# code). If you need this, I would suggest opening the CommunicatorAPI.dll assembly in Reflector.